# Automatic scroll with ScrollView in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, scrollview

I have a list of comments in my app and I would like that when the user accesses the notification, the app would automatically scroll to the comment.

My code is like this:

comments.tsx

```js
const scrollViewRef = useRef(null)
const commentRef = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {
    if(scrollViewRef.current && commentRef.current)
        commentRef.current?.measureLayout(
              scrollViewRef.current,
              (x, y) => {
                scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({x: 0, y, animated: true})
              }
            )
}, [scrollViewRef.current, commentRef.current])

<ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
        ...
        <Comments>
             {comments.map(comment => {
                 <Comment ref={commentId === commentIdNotification ? commentRef : null} />
             )}
        </Comments>
</ScrollView>
```

The problem is that the measureLayout value is usually wrong and doesn't go to the comment. I believe it is a problem with the rendering since the component makes several requests to APIs and takes a while to finish rendering.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason for using a ScrollView with a map-function instead of a FlatList with the Comment-component as renderItem? You will probably get better control and performance with a FlatList.

In that case, you can simply call FlatLists scrollToIndex().

See documentation here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex

Comment: It was made that way because there are other elements on the screen besides the comments. Unfortunately I can't replace it with a FlatList.

Comment: I understand. Are those other element not possible to add to the header or footer on the flatlist? (ListHeaderComponent/ListFooterComponent)

Comment: It would be a good solution, I'm just not sure if it will work. The screen contains a video banner along with a description. Comments are at the bottom of the page, and are hidden until the user taps the button to display them. Do you think it would be good?

Comment: Hmm.. tricky. I see a few solutions.
1. Use the video on the header of flatlist
2. Use a sectionList with the video as one section (will be a bit hacky, I created a quick example here: https://snack.expo.dev/@jtrowald/cd5d3d)
3. Always have a fixed height for your comments. If the comment doesn't fit, have a "more" button to expand it. It will be easier to calc how far to scroll. But with the map function, you will quickly lose performance when the list of comments grows longer.